# Play notification tone from app in wp8.1 rt

Tags: c#, audio, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

We have a requirement where we need to play notification tone inside app when message is received.

For this if a song is getting played in background and notification comes then behaviour should be:

1. Background song/audio should get paused.
2. Notification tone should
   get played.
3. Background song should get resumed from where it was
   paused.

But I went through following links to play audio file through app:

1)http://www.jayway.com/2014/04/24/windows-phone-8-1-for-developers-the-background-media-player/
This stops music in background.

2)http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johnkenn/archive/2013/12/31/supporting-background-audio-in-your-windows-8-1-app.aspx

3)https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.media.systemmediatransportcontrols.aspx

But none of these served my purpose.

In wp8, we could do it in this [way](http://henry-chong.com/pro-tip-including-background-music-for-your-windows-phone-app).

Any direction to achieve desired functionality?

Answer (score 0):

If you are sending toast notifications to your users when they receive a message, include a custom sound in your notification payload by including the `audio` tag:

```
    <toast launch=\"$param\">
       <audio src=\"ms-appx:///Assets/Sounds/$sound.wav\"/>
       <visual>
           <binding template=\"ToastText02\">
               <text id=\"1\">$title</text>
               <text id=\"2\">$msg</text>
           </binding>
       </visual>
    </toast>
```

For the custom sound to work, you need to include the `sound.wav` in your project and you can specify the path. I am putting it in my `Assets/Sounds/` folder, you can specify something else.

You can also try to send a toast with sound, from within you app when you receive a message:

```
var notificationContent = "...xml...";
var xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
xmlDocument.LoadXml(notificationContent);
var toastNotification = new ToastNotification(xmlDocument);
toastNotification.SuppressPopup = true;
ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier().Show(toastNotification);
```

where `notificationContent` is of the same format as the above XML, just escaped.

Comment: I want to notification tone inside app. For toast its working fine.